# Comando "dotnet run" muito lento

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

Quando eu executo o comando *dotnet run* via linha de comando em meu projeto ASP.NET Core tenho que esperar de 8 à 10 segundos até poder acessar o navegador para testar alguma alteração. Baixei o Visual Studio 2017, consigo executar a aplicação tranquilamente se iniciar sem debug (CTRL + F5), leva em torno de 3 ou 4 segundos. Ao iniciar com debug (F5), tenho tempos parecidos ao executando via linha de comando. Qual o motivo dessa lentidão do dotnet run? Existe algum equivalente para o iniciar sem debug do VS para a linha de comando?

Answer (score -1):

Era pra ser justamente o contrário. Via .NET CLI ser mais rápido.
Faça um teste com `dotnet run nomedoprojeto` e depois com `dotnet nomedoprojeto.dll`. Executando diretamente na dll a diferença é notável.